# How do I prevent capistrano from overwriting files uploaded by users in their own folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano and git to deploy a RoR app. I have a folder under which each user has their own folder. When a user uploads or saves a file, it is saved in their own folder.

When I deploy new versions of the code to the server, the user files and folders are overwritten with what's on my dev machine.

Is there a way to ignore some folders in capistrano, like we do in git? This post - http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/97539 - suggests using symlinks and storing the user files in a shared folder. But it's an old post, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it now.

Also, does anyone know of any good screencasts/tutorials to recommend for using RoR+git+capistrano?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should move the user's folders outside of Capistrano's `releases` directory. The usual approach is to have Capistrano create symbolic links to the directories that should be preserved across deployments.

Here's an example from my Rails blog application's `config/deploy.rb` whereby files for download within blog posts and images used within posts are stored in a `shared` directory:

```
after :deploy, 'deploy:link_dependencies'

namespace :deploy do
  desc <<-DESC
    Creates symbolic links to configuration files and other dependencies
    after deployment.
  DESC
  task :link_dependencies, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/public/files #{release_path}/public/files"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/public/images/posts #{release_path}/public/images/posts"
  end
end
```

- To answer your second question, I recommend [PeepCode](http://peepcode.com/) and [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)

Comment: Thanks John, symbolic links it is then.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late but I ran into this problem. I use rails 5 and capistrano 3.6. I solved this problem by creating symlink to shared folder.

You might already have this line in your deploy.rb

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle}
```

If you want to save user's images in public/images/user_images and symlink it to shared folder then add the folder name with a space (like this):

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/images/user_images}
```

Now run `cap production deploy` and you should be able to access the images in shared folder.